# How can I do this redirection from ballerinalang?

Tags: redirect, ballerina

I've implemented a REST endpoint in ballerinalang called `https://localhost:9090/isValidUser`. And here is my code below

```
import ballerina.net.http;

@http:configuration {
    basePath:"/",
    httpsPort:9090,
    keyStoreFile:"${ballerina.home}/bre/security/wso2carbon.jks",
    keyStorePassword:"wso2carbon",
    certPassword:"wso2carbon",
    trustStoreFile:"${ballerina.home}/bre/security/client-truststore.jks",
    trustStorePassword:"wso2carbon"
}
service<http> authentication {
    @http:resourceConfig {
        methods:["POST"],
        path:"/isValidUser"
    }

    resource isValidUser (http:Request req, http:Response res) {
        println(req.getHeaders());
        res.send();

    }
}
```

Now I need to do is when I invoke that URL from the browser, I need to redirect the user to another URL called `https://localhost:3000` after some validations happen within my service.

So how can I do this redirection from ballerinalang?

Answer (score 1):

Ballerina has provided smooth API to do the redirection. Please check following code which elaborates the Listener endpoint redirection.

```
service<http:Service> redirect1 bind {port:9090} {
    @http:ResourceConfig {
        methods:["GET"],
        path:"/"
    }
    redirect1 (endpoint client, http:Request req) {
        http:Response res = new;
        _ = client -> redirect(res, http:REDIRECT_TEMPORARY_REDIRECT_307,
            ["http://localhost:9093/redirect2"]);
    }
}
```

The complete example is available in 
[Ballerina Redirects](https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/http-redirects.html)

Answer (score 0):

In Ballerina, you need to handle the redirects yourself by setting the necessary headers and status code. The following example is a simple demo of how you can redirect in Ballerina. (note: I tried this in Ballerina 0.95.2)

```
import ballerina.net.http;

@http:configuration {basePath:"/hello"}
service<http> helloWorld {

    @http:resourceConfig {
        methods:["GET"],
        path:"/"
    }
    resource sayHello (http:Request request, http:Response response) {
        map qParams = request.getQueryParams();
        var name, _ = (string)qParams.name;

        if (isExistingUser(name)) {
            response.setStringPayload("Hello Ballerina!");
        } else {
            response.setHeader("Location", "http://localhost:9090/hello/newUser");
            response.setStatusCode(302);
        }

        _ = response.send();
    }

    @http:resourceConfig {path:"/newUser"}
    resource newUser (http:Request request, http:Response response) {
        string msg = "New to Ballerina? Welcome!";
        response.setStringPayload(msg);
        _ = response.send();
    }
}

function isExistingUser (string name) (boolean) {
    return name == "Ballerina";
}
```